# Save Audio files to Photo Album Library iPhone Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to save My Audio Files to Photo Album like Video and Image Save to Photo Album.

Comment: did you search for this before asking here? there are plenty of answers... ask Mr. Google, he will surely help you...

Comment: Also, https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the below code. its working for me. We can store Audio/Video files using this code.

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sub" ofType:@"caf"], nil, nil, nil); //  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sub" ofType:@"caf"] is Url path.
```

Thanks